# How can I get more current out of my Arduino Nano 33 IoT?

Tags: arduino, power

I'm currently using an Arduino Nano 33 IoT and would be powering 18 transistors - one digital pin to 1 transistor and with the use of the SDA and SCL pin to connect to 3 other I2C devices.  I have run into an issue where my Nano 33 IoT will just switch off upon connecting the USB to my laptop. I suspect a power supply issue.

Is there any way I can power my Arduino to get it to output more current? I researched about the Vin pin when it can take in 7 to 21V external power supply but it seems there is a voltage regulator to regulate it back to 5V, so what is the point of using the Vin?

The 5V supplying the relay comes from the Vusb Pin of the Arduino

[image]

Comment: How did you connect to the transistor? It is more likely that you made an error in the connections that not being able to power 18 transistors. Unless you also power heavy loads from the USB supply. The point of VIN is to power the circuit standalone without USB with external supply that can be larger than 5V and still be able to make the 5V required by chips onboard. So show a diagram what you connected, where, and how. Including resistors if any. And the transistor type.

Comment: @Justme Hi, thanks for the reply! Apologies, I shall try to get a diagram up, but the diagram is really complicated due to the amount of components I have. Do take a look and I'll be happy to clarify! I have added the diagram!

Comment: If you've got many channels with the same output circuit then just detail one of them, put a dotted outline around it and just show the outline for the other outputs. Oooh, too late. We've got the whole thing! Thanks.

Comment: We'll need a higher resolution image, I think.

Comment: Your question didn't mention anything about having twenty relays. They're powered from +5 V. Where is that coming from? Not the poor little Nano, I hope!

Comment: @Transistor Hello! I have updated a better picture. I shown one of the connections, however, there is actually 18 more of these. Apologies, completely missed out on the relays and unfortunately, I connected the 5V to a rail to all the other circuits

Comment: @ArduinoRookie You left out which components those are. The resistor value in ohms, transistor model, and relay model. And the fact that you are powring 18 relays, not 18 transistors. And likely the relays can damage the transistors and Arduino since you left out a snubber diode from the coil.

Comment: Hi @Arduino Rookie For this, it is better to use the Darlington  (for example ULN2003BPWR). Or if it is necessary for you to put single transistors, then you have to use MOSFET instead of BJT, which of course costs more.

Comment: You need to look at the relay coil resistance (link to datasheet in question would be helpful - but please not an Amazon ad link), calculate the current draw when the relay is on and compare that to the max the Nano can handle. (Give a datasheet link for that too.)

Comment: Hi @Alirezaagha30, thanks for the reply! Oh I see, is there a way to retain using BJT as my components have been soldered?

Comment: @Justme I've updated with the relay and bjt model together with the resistor values.

Comment: @Transistor https://www.datasheetcafe.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/SRS-05VDC-SL.pdf This is the datasheet for the relay - I used the value of SRS(Z) Standard which is 75 ohms for 5V. Regarding the arduino max current, i could never find a value for it from the datasheet - https://docs.arduino.cc/resources/datasheets/ABX00027-datasheet.pdf. Is there a way for me to find out?

Comment: Since you're trying to draw a very large amount of power for all those relays, a better question might be how much current your laptop can supply?  You're well above what the USB spec allows, so good chance it is powering down the USB port to avoid damage.

Comment: @user1850479 Hi thanks for the reply! I see, actually for this project i might also connect the arduino via a usb port to the wall plug with a phone charger, this way i might be able to receive more amps? Is this possible?

Comment: To all, would it be viable if i power my Arduino via the Vin pin with a Li-On/Li-Po battery of higher voltage but still within the acceptable range so that the arduino can output more current?

Comment: In the arduino website, it states that "3. On-board DC-DC power supply enables the board to be powered up to 21V maintaining high efficiency and offering a lot of current to external devices without overheating. This is a big improvement over other products on the market that have LDO and heat up quite a bit when powered at high voltages." If i understood this sentence right, it means powering through the Vin pin i could get the corresponding currents of my input voltage to power my individual pins?

Comment: Please draw the entire schematic, including power supply. You don't need to replicate all 18 channels, but include the full schematic of at least one. Where does 5 V come from?

Comment: @winny Hello, the 5V comes from the Vusb pin of the Arduino!

Comment: Your question has been closed as unclear. Please update or draw a new schematic. A USB supply will probably shut down due to relay inrush current.

Answer (score 1):

The 100 ohm base resistor is too small and allows too much current out from MCU IO pin. IO pins are rated for 7mA max and with 100 ohm resistor there could be more than double that. About 1mA would be enough.

Also you can't simultaneously power 18 relays that take 70mA each. Unless you enumerate with USB requesting the amount of current you need and get a permission to continue drawing that current. You can draw max 100mA without asking. 18 relays alone takes 1.3A which is absolute over the safe limit you can assume to draw, either from USB or through Arduino onboard 5V regulator.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer! ohh i see, in the current situation, would it be possible by powering up the arduino via the Vin pin and get a higher current output from the external supply?

Comment: @ArduinoRookie Maybe but the relays still consume a lot of 5V so why bother feeding the external 5V through the VIn anyway but directly to the relays.

Comment: Ah i was thinking of powering the relays with a higher voltage supply and just supplying the arduino through Vin pin for higher current output to control the relays.

Answer (score 0):

You need to recalculate your base resistor. As far as I can see from the datasheet the relay has a coil resistance of 70 ohms needing a current of 71ma.

The transistor has minimum DC gain at that current of 100 giving a base current of .71ma. Over 4.3V that gives a resistance of 6056 ohms you want to be a bit lower than that to get into saturation so say 5.6K

That will greatly reduce your current requirement or as an alternative you could use a MOSFET.

Comment: Hi Roy! Thank you for the calculations! I would like to clarify regarding the DC gain as I wasn't that sure as well when I was doing the calculations a few months back, in my context of operating the transistor as a switch, would the DC gain be considered as I do not need any amplifications in my project? Thanks!

Comment: Yes it would.....

Comment: Okay, thank you very much! With the MOSFET, would my base resistor calculations be the same?

Comment: No a MOSFET gate is voltage driven not current it does not take any current to drive it at DC. Search on this site for MOSFET relay driver.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much!

Comment: Hi @RoyC, just to check. Why did you use 5V instead of 3.3V to calculate the resistor base value if the formulation is Vb-Vbe / Ib since Vb is supplied by the pins of the arduino which is 3.3v?

Comment: I saw 5V on your diagram and in your text I missed that the Arduino is 3.3V. Use the formula you gave it will give a lower resistor use a 5-10% lower value to ensure saturation.